# How to add a text in Word with Hyperlink using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I need a simple example of how to add a new text in word and change this text to a hyperlink

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.visible = $true
$document = $word.Documents.Add()          
$document.Activate()

$range = $document.content
$null = $document.HyperLinks.Add($Range, 
'https://www.google.com/',$null,$null,'This is Google')
```

Thanks